# jQuery hiding child element opens its child

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

Im using a table and rows can have child rows and it can go down a few levels,
what is happening now is that when hiding a child element it then opens that childs child element.

Heres my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getChildren($row) {
        var children = [], level = $row.attr('data-level');
        while($row.next().attr('data-level') > level) {
             children.push($row.next());
             $row = $row.next();
        }            
        return children;
    }        
    $('.parent').on('click', function() {
        var children = getChildren($(this));
        $.each(children, function() {
            $(this).toggle();
        })
    });
    $(".parent a").click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
    })
})
```

I have set up a jsfiddle so you can see whats happening

https://jsfiddle.net/rhvye8k0/4/

If you click the first "+" you will see what im trying to describe.

Cant think how to sort it out

---

Update,

have sorted it and updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rhvye8k0/5/

There may be a way to reduce the jQuery but it works for now

Comment: issue is with data-level values. make sure they are correct

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `$(this).toggle();` in `.parent`'s onclick handler. The `tr` at level 3 has `style="display:none"`, the others don't. `toggle()` will toggle the receiving element(s) visibility so the others are show (their `display` is implicitly `block`) and level 3's is hidden.

Comment: I had thought it was going to be something to do with that. ill need to think of a way to change it